# How to update certain positions of a text line (substring in Bash)

Tags: bash, shell, sed, substring

Hi I'm new on shell programming and I'm facing the following problem, I'm merging two files so I need to update the footer in the positions that represents number of lines in my new file, the original footers looks as follows:

```
90000000000100000000000012345...n
90000000000300000000000012345...n
```

the number of lines is represented in positions 2 to 13 E.g.

```
9[000000000010]0000000000012345...n
9[000000000030]0000000000012345...n
```

I'm using the following instruction

```
newfooter=`sed 1d $newfile | awk -v completeline=$originalfooter'{total_lines+=1}END{printf "%1d%012d%d\n", substr(completeline, 1, 1), total_lines, substr(completeline, 14)}'`
```

but my result is the following:

```
90000000000412345...n
```

As you can see the sum of the total lines is ok once `000000000010` + `000000000030` = `000000000040` but the next 11 positions in the line are getting lost, the result I'm trying to get should be as follows:

```
90000000000400000000000012345...n
```

I'm honestly completely lost, Thanks is advance for your help

Comment: I think you have to indicate the zero padding for the last section in the `printf` format. Something like what you have for the second section, that `%012d`.

Comment: If I counted well, you'd be missing a `%017d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` might be a better tool to manipulate the string

```
originalfooter='90000000000300000000000012345...n'
# format number
num=$(printf "%012d" 57)
# replace in original footer
echo "$originalfooter" | sed -re "s/([0-9])[0-9]{12}(.*)/\1$num\2/" 

# result: 90000000000570000000000012345...n
```

A bit different approach

```
originalfooter='90000000000300000000000012345...n'
num=$(printf "%012d" 57)
newFooter=$(sed -re "s/([0-9])[0-9]{12}(.*)/\1$num\2/" <<< "$originalfooter")
echo "$newFooter"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the zero padding in the last section of the `printf`.

Try changing your `printf "%1d%012d%d\n"`
by a `printf "%1d%012d%017d\n"`.

That should tell the `printf` code you want 17 digits for your last number, filling with zeroes on the left if the number is smaller than those 17 digits.

Comment: The problem with this is that I can't  assume that those 11 positions will be always zeros, the idea is that those 11 positions must stay the same as the original footer

Comment: At the moment you're grabbing 14 characters from the original footer (see `substr(completeline, 14)`) and printing them without any padding. That's why, if they fit in 5 digits as in your example (`12345`), they are printed in 5 digits. If they were 10 or 14 digits, 10 or 14 digits would be printed. If you want no padding, but you always want to print `n` characters, you have to use `%nd`, `n` being a number.

Comment: The thing is, the length of my footer is larger than the example, so each position has a purpose, thats why I can't take mote than my 12 positions for my total lines  the following zero afer my represenntation of lines is part of 
different data [9][000000000040][000000000001234567][00015][...etc][][]... So I need to update just the second segment [000000000040] with the total_lines value filling with zeros the 12 positions and keep the rest of the line as it is

Comment: because in this example there are 11 zeros after my total lines valie but in other file could be less or more zeros depending on data, so if I take at least one more position I will alterate all the information in the footer

Comment: But the third section always has a fixed length, hasn't it? You just have to, for example, read 14 digits whatever they are, zeroes or not, and then print them. Your script is reading 14 digits but trimming all the zeroes to the left before printing them. If I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

above seems close (exact?) but this works too I think:

```
Mac_3.2.57$newfooter=`cat newfile | awk -v completeline=$originalfooter '{total_lines+=1}; END {printf("%s%012.12d%s\n", substr(completeline, 1, 1), total_lines, substr(completeline, 14))}'`
Mac_3.2.57$echo $newfooter
90000000000300000000000012345...n
Mac_3.2.57$cat newfile | wc -l
      30
Mac_3.2.57$
```

Answer (score 0):

While others have suggested changing `%d` to `%012d` (or `%017d`), the issue is a bit simpler.

Consider the following:

```
awk -v x='000001' 'BEGIN{printf "%d", x}'
1                                          # leading zeros are dropped

awk -v x='000001' 'BEGIN{printf "%06d",x}'
000001                                     # leading zeros are dropped and then added back
```

These examples (`%d` / `%06d`) tell `printf` to treat the argument as integer/numeric.

As OP has mentioned in comments, what's really desired is to keep whatever makes up the 'rest of the line'.

We can accomplish this by switching out the `%d` with a `%s` which tells `printf` that it's dealing with a string:

```
awk -v x='000001' 'BEGIN{printf "%s", x}'
000001                                     # string is printed as is, no dropping/adding of 0's
```

This means OP should be able to get the desired output with the following:

```
printf "%1d%012d%s\n" ...
```

In fact, the leading `%1d` could be replaced with a `%s`, too:

```
printf "%s%012d%s\n" ...
```

**NOTE:** the use of `%s` for parts of the 'footer' that aren't changing means that non-numerics (if they could exist) will be maintained as opposed to causing problems and/or being dropped if using `%d`

Cutting OP's `awk` code down to a demo:

```
$ x='90000000000100000000000012345...n'

# current printf format:

$ awk -v x="${x}" 'BEGIN{printf "%1d%012d%d\n", substr(x,1,1), "40", substr(x,14)}'
900000000004012345

# proposed printf format:

$ awk -v x="${x}" 'BEGIN{printf "%s%012d%s\n", substr(x,1,1), "40", substr(x,14)}'
90000000000400000000000012345...n
```